# How to change the content of a 2d array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, memory-address

I am working on a problem where I have to transpose a matrix. I am passing the address of the original matrix, but once I execute the function it does not change!

I have tried to add a * infront of  matrix in the transpose function, thinking that it will be pointing to the whole 2d array, but it did not work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void transpose(int *r,int *c, int **matrix);
void printMatrix(int r,int c, int **matrix){
  for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
        printf("%2d ",matrix[i][j]);
      printf("\n");  
  }
}

int main() {

  int **matrix;
  int r =3;
  int c =2;
  matrix = (int**) malloc(r*sizeof(int*)); 
  for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    matrix[i] = (int*) malloc(c*sizeof(int));

   for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
        matrix[i][j] = (3*i+2*j)%8+1; 
  }
  printf("Before transpose:\n");
  printMatrix(r,c,matrix);

   transpose(&r, &c ,matrix);

  printMatrix(r,c,matrix);



return 0;
}

void transpose(int *r,int *c, int **matrix){
  int newR = *c;
  int newC = *r;
  int **newMatrix;

  newMatrix = (int**) malloc(newR*(sizeof(int*)));
  for(int i=0; i<newR;i++)
    newMatrix[i] = (int*) malloc(newC*(sizeof(int)));
  for(int i=0; i<newR; i++)
    for(int j=0;j<newC;j++)
      newMatrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];

  *c = newC;
  *r = newR;



  matrix = (int**) malloc((*r)*sizeof(int*)); 
  for(int i=0;i<*r;i++)
    matrix[i] = (int*) malloc((*c)*sizeof(int));
  for(int i=0; i<newR; i++){
    for(int j=0;j<newC;j++){
      matrix[i][j] = newMatrix[i][j];
    }
 printf("\n");  
  }
}
```

I have this matrix

```
1 3
4 6
7 1
```

and want to get

```
1 4 7 
3 6 1
```

however I am getting

```
1 3 0
1 4 0
```

Comment: How is the caller supposed to even see the new matrix?  You create it locally, fill it in, then return.  At that point it's dead.  The caller never sees it.  You need to return the new pointer (or pass an `int ***` and set it through that).

Comment: the `transpose` function never makes the new matrix available to the caller

Comment: @M.M assuming it is not meant to mutate `int **matrix`, which does look like it is maybe the intent.

Comment: @Kbiir Not directly related, but often for dynamic 2D arrays you may want to consider using 1D array and something like `arr[column * width + row]`. This keeps it in a single memory block, less memory, no extra indirection, single `malloc`, single `free` (perhaps the easiest bit to forget and then leak).

Comment: Note: This is not a 2D array - it's a 1D array of pointers to 1D arrays. A 2D array (e.g. `matrix = malloc(r*c*sizeof(int));`) is likely to be faster and cost a lot less memory.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you forgot to do was actually *use* the transposed matrix. All I did was change the function signature and return the matrix you had already allocated and manipulated, and I got the output you were looking for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int** transpose(int *r,int *c, int **matrix);

void printMatrix(int r, int c, int **matrix) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < r; ++i){
        for (size_t j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
            printf("%2d ",matrix[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");  
    }
}

int main()
{
    int r = 3;
    int c = 2;

    int **matrix = calloc(sizeof(int*), r);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < r; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = calloc(sizeof(int), c);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < r; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
            matrix[i][j] = (3 * i + 2 * j) % 8 + 1; 
        }
    }

    printf("Before transpose:\n");
    printMatrix(r, c, matrix);

    int** newMatrix = transpose(&r, &c ,matrix);

    printMatrix(r, c, newMatrix);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int** transpose(int *r, int *c, int **matrix) {
    int newR = *c;
    int newC = *r;

    int **newMatrix = calloc((sizeof(int*)), newR);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < newR; ++i) {
        newMatrix[i] = (int*) malloc(newC*(sizeof(int)));
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < newR; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < newC; ++j) {
            newMatrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
        }
    }

    *c = newC;
    *r = newR;

    matrix = calloc(sizeof(int*), *r); 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < *r; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = calloc(sizeof(int), *c);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < newR; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < newC; ++j) {
            matrix[i][j] = newMatrix[i][j];
        }

        printf("\n");  
    }

    return newMatrix;
}
```

Output:

```
1 4 7
3 6 1
```

I changed a few things, especially because I prefer using `calloc` over `malloc`, since it zeroes out the newly-allocated memory, and there is a dedicated parameter for the size of the requested memory, which I think semantically is a better idea.

As a side note, you don't have to cast the result of `malloc` in C. I tend to feel more strongly about that than other people, I think, because code noise, especially when you're working in C is one of the worst things you can do to yourself. This is a pretty good example of that, since all I did was reformat your code and the answer was right there. Don't be stingy with the whitespace, either; it really does make a difference.

Anyways, I hope this helped somewhat, even if you literally had basically everything done.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void transpose(int *r,int *c, int ***matrix);
void printMatrix(int r,int c, int **matrix){
    int i=0,j=0;
  for(i=0;i<r;i++){
      for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        printf("%2d ",matrix[i][j]);
      printf("\n");  
  }
}

int main() {

  int **matrix;
  int r =3;
  int c =2;
  int i=0,j=0;

  matrix = (int**) malloc(r*sizeof(int*)); 
  for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    matrix[i] = (int*) malloc(c*sizeof(int));

   for(i=0;i<r;i++){
      for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        matrix[i][j] = (3*i+2*j)%8+1; 
  }
  printf("Before transpose:\n");
  printMatrix(r,c,matrix);

   transpose(&r, &c, &matrix);

  printMatrix(r,c,matrix);



return 0;
}

void transpose(int *r,int *c, int ***matrix){
  int newR = *c;
  int newC = *r;
  int **newMatrix;
  int i=0,j=0;

  newMatrix = (int**) malloc(newR*(sizeof(int*)));
  for(i=0; i<newR;i++)
    newMatrix[i] = (int*) malloc(newC*(sizeof(int)));
  for(i=0; i<newR; i++)
    for(j=0;j<newC;j++) {
      newMatrix[i][j] = (*matrix)[j][i];
    }

  *c = newC;
  *r = newR;

  // free matrix..

  *matrix = newMatrix;


  /*matrix = (int**) malloc((*r)*sizeof(int*)); 
  for(i=0;i<*r;i++)
    matrix[i] = (int*) malloc((*c)*sizeof(int));
  for(i=0; i<newR; i++){
    for(j=0;j<newC;j++){
      matrix[i][j] = newMatrix[i][j];
    }
 printf("\n");  
  }*/

}
```

Comment: You are expected to briefly explain WHY the original code was not working and HOW you have made it working. You should not just post the code.